# XPATH and CSS locators throws error for Chrome in webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing issues in locating element in chrome. 
XPath of the element looks this way:

```
//*[@id="signin"] (right click on the element and copy xpath)
```

CSS for the same:

```
$$("div[id='signin']")
```

Now I am able to locate the element in chrome when I hover over them manually. But when I try to implement the same as code it throws error.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("$$("div[id='signin']")).click(); - CSS
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="signin"]")).click(); - XPATH
```

It throws `remove argument to match 'xpath(String)'`
Help!!

**Code :**

```
public static WebDriver driver;


@BeforeClass
public static void start()
{
    File file = new File("D:/new/chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://abcd.com");
}


@AfterClass
public static void close()
{
    driver.close();
}


@Test
public static void test()

    {
    driver.findElement(By.name("UserId")).sendKeys("100");
    driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys("100");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signin']")).click();


    }

}
```

**@NOte : the URL here is dummy. in the real time am using a proper URL. It throws the below error**

> FAILED: test
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: The element could not be found (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 89 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'

Comment: Then the XPath itself is wrong - we'd need to see exactly what HTML/webpage you are doing this against.

Comment: @Arram : I am sorry :( ... Guess its confidential.. Not suppose to share it.. :( is there someother to make this work

Answer (score 2):

Try enclosing the `signin` in single quotes instead of double quotes as shown below.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signin']")).click(); - XPATH
```

Comment: Tried tat before posting the question :) still its not recognizing the element :(

Comment: @user2248949: It does look like you have problems with double-quotes in your string literals; best to clean those up and post your most recent code in the question.

Comment: @Sriram As now, the error is `The element could not be found `, try to see if the elements are present inside a frame. If so, switch to the frame before performing operations on the elements.

Comment: @HemChe : Its still not working.. I have posted the updated code up here.. for BeforeMethod alone..

Comment: Can you give the link of the webpage if it is not confidential? because i have faced the same error while testing stackoverflow home page. when i changed the quotes to single quotes, it worked.

Comment: @HemChe : I am sorry :( ... Guess its confidential.. Not suppose to share it.. :( is there someother way to make this work

Comment: Is it not working when you are trying to find the element using it's id `signin` ?

Comment: Yes... I tried with xpath too.. the application works only in chrome so not able to verify in other browsers :(

Comment: Not xpath. i am asking whether you have tried the following code using `driver.findElement(By.id("signin"));`

Comment: Are you sure that signin button is not present inside an iframe?

Comment: @HemChe : if at all if it is within an iframe what should i do.

Comment: You need to switch to that iframe first.

Answer (score 0):

From the CSS you mentioned it seems that it is div element that you trying to find out.Following should work seamlessly for this.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='signin']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#signin")).click(); - CSS

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signin']")).click(); - Xpath

driver.findElement(By.id("signin")).click(); - Id